# Adding progress bar to pyAesCrypt

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to add a progress bar to my code, but pyAesCrypt blocks other code execution until the encryption/decryption has completed. When encrypting/decrypting the window doesn't respond until it has finished. I would like an opening terminal with a tqdm progress bar or a tkinter progress bar with percentage (An example: calculating the progress from the input file and the output file). (This project is also available on GitHub). Any help will be appreciated

Here's the code:

```
import pyAesCrypt
import tkinter as tk
import easygui
import os
from os import stat, remove
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *
import sys

password = ""

window = tk.Tk()
expvar = tkinter.IntVar()
exp = Checkbutton(text="Show file in explorer when done", variable=expvar)
exp.pack()

bufferSize = 128 * 1024


def warn_nokey():
    easygui.msgbox("No key loaded. please load one.", ok_button="Load/Generate key")
    initkey = easygui.choicebox("Do you want to generate a new key or load an existing key?",
                                choices=['Load', 'Generate', 'Exit'])
    if initkey == "Load":
        pwd()
    elif initkey == "Generate":
        keygen()
    else:
        sys.exit(0)


def pwd():
    global password
    try:
        password = open(easygui.fileopenbox(filetypes=["*.key"], default="*.key")).read()
    except TypeError:
        pass


def keygen():
    global password
    try:
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        password = easygui.filesavebox(filetypes=["key.key"], default="key.key")
        with open(password, 'wb') as filekey:
            filekey.write(key)
        passwd = key
        password = passwd.decode("utf-8")
        password.replace(" ", password)
    except TypeError:
        pass


def encrypt():
    if password == "" or None:
        warn_nokey()
    else:
        try:
            file = easygui.fileopenbox()
            name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            with open(file, "rb") as fIn:
                with open(str(name) + ".tmp", "wb") as fOut:
                    pyAesCrypt.encryptStream(fIn, fOut, password, bufferSize)
            remove(file)
            os.rename(name + ".tmp", file)
            if expvar.get() == 1:
                os.system("explorer /select," + str(file))
            else:
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Encryption", "Done! File saved to " + file)

        except TypeError:
            pass


def decrypt():
    if password == "" or None:
        warn_nokey()
    else:
        try:
            file = easygui.fileopenbox(filetypes=["*.*"], default="*.*")
            encfilesize = stat(file).st_size
            name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            with open(file, "rb") as fIn:
                try:
                    with open(str(name) + ".tmp", "wb") as fOut:
                        pyAesCrypt.decryptStream(fIn, fOut, password, bufferSize, encfilesize)
                except ValueError:
                    remove(file)

            remove(file)
            os.rename(name + ".tmp", file)
            if expvar.get() == 1:
                os.system("explorer /select," + file)
            else:
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Encryption", "Done! File saved to " + file)

        except TypeError:
            pass


def keyprint():
    try:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Key", "Key: " + password)
    except TypeError:
        warn_nokey()


window.title("Encrypt V4.1")
window.geometry("854x480")
newkey = tk.Button(text="Load a key", command=pwd)
newkey.pack()
keygener = tk.Button(text="Generate a new key", command=keygen)
keygener.pack()
enc = tk.Button(text="Encrypt", command=encrypt)
enc.pack()
decr = tk.Button(text="Decrypt", command=decrypt)
decr.pack()
printkey = tk.Button(text="Print the key", command=keyprint)
printkey.pack()
alert = tk.Text(window)
alert.insert(tk.INSERT, """NOTE: For large files it can take some minutes. When done, you will be warned.
WARNING: DO NOT INTERACT WITH THE WINDOW DURING ENCRYPTION/DECRYPTION PROCESS, AS THE WINDOW WILL NOT RESPOND.""")
alert.pack()
if password == "" or " ":
    warn_nokey()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways around this.

1. Do a feature request / code donation where the streaming API takes a listener or call-back function (this is the neat solution) which gets called after a specific amount of bytes processed and at the end of the stream.
2. Split the encryption in multiple chunks of X blocks of size N=16 bytes (for AES) and stream-encrypt/decrypt them separately. Then you can use the last ciphertext block in the previous chunk as IV to continue encrypting. This you can do without changing the pyAesCrypto implementation.

Beware that if you use streaming that the stream doesn't know how many bytes to expect. So the listener can only be informed after a specific amount of bytes and the end of the stream. I.e. if you want to have a percentage calculated you should not do that in the callback function, not in the streaming API.

Please always separate the business / encryption logic from the GUI elements.

Comment: What's the code to split the binary stream?

Comment: Sorry, currently I do not have the time to code it. Look at the CBC mode of operation on Wikipedia to get a better idea. You create multiple streams and combine them to one output in sequence.